# Chat bot logic and variables within bot (activate extra search functions)

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, chatbot

Hello I've been working on a chat bot. Everything worked fine. I managed to avoid some logical conflicts by applying lens or type.

Main problem with bot response. Since json file might include several thousands and we expect only 10-1000 responses, somehow I gotta stop get_users from getting all users before comparing with profile_count. Also I gotta combine all ages count, if we just do in range (profile_count), it will compare only with min_age, gotta solve the case for small users count.

```
get_users(user_id):
  user_list = []
  for age in range(min_age, max_age + 1):
    data = get_user_json()
    count = data['count']
    for user in data['items']
      first_name = user['first_name']
      last_name = user['last_name']
      if check_database(conn, user_id=user_id) is None:
         user_list.append([first_name, last_name, age])
  return user_list   

count = 0
for event in bot.listen.fucntion()
  greetings = [hi, hello]
  id = event.user_id
  if msg in greetings:
    send_message(user_id, f'Hello User {user_id}. Type "search" to start searching, or type "count" to set number of profiles.'
  elif msg == "count"
    count = 1
  elif count == 1:
    try:
      if int(msg) in range(1, 1001):
        profile_count == int(msg) or 100
        send_message(user_id, f'Profiles number is set to {msg}'
      else:    
        send_message(user_id, 'Incorrect number. Please use numbers from 1 to 1000'
    except:
      continue
  elif msg == "search"
   try:
     with connect(database="", user="", password="") as conn:
       create_table(conn)
       for user in get_users(user_id=id)[:profile_count]
         send_message(user_id, f'Name: {get_users[0] get_users[1]}. They are {user[2]}.'
   except:
     send_message(user_id, 'An unexpected error occurred. Try later'
```

Ok thx for count = 0 before for event.
Now I have problem with loading time. So, the function works with thousands users in request, profile count is less than a thousand. Inside get_users(conn) I have for age in range(min_age, max_age+1). Somehow I need to compare profile_count to age['count'] in request.json. Something like if profile count less than min_age['count'], we break the cycle "for age" and work only with first age(min_age). That counting takes about 10 seconds, we don't need that for 100 user_profiles.

Comment: Can you please post the actual code you are using? What you've posted here isn't runnable (due to `...`, missing colons etc)

Comment: sorry I import bot's api it's unrunnable since you need authorization. I might write actual code instead of music example.

Comment: You have `count=0` as the first statement of the `for` loop, so `count` is reset to 0 on every iteration. Instead, put `count=0` __before__ the loop.

Comment: Thx a lot. I also figured out I must put count = 0 in try loop in order to escape it, otherwise it is inifinite.

Answer (score 0):

count = 0 before
for event

```
profile_count = 100
if len(user_list) > profile_count
  break
```

filter user_list through database, user_id should not be in the database in order to append user_list