# Chat bot (vk) logic, how to use global variables (dictionary) inside bot for every user

Tags: python, dictionary, logic, chatbot

I am finishing bot from [Chat bot logic and variables within bot (activate extra search functions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76004009/chat-bot-logic-and-variables-within-bot-activate-extra-search-functions)

So, I used global vairables and everything went fine. Then I decided to use boolean, previous line:

```
greetings = [hi, hello]
  if msg in greetings:
```

Became:

```
if first_message is False:
```

Then I made several variables like first_message (age, extended_options) and put it in dict options = {'first_message': False, 'extended_options': False, etc}:

```
if options['first_message'] is False:
```

The obvious issue is, when several people get access to the bot, it rewrites all the values and bot shows results according to last overwrite. Whether it is only options dictionary issue, or major flaw, if I try to copy options dict like:

```
options = options_orig.copy()
```

It simply get stuck at option['first_message'], it is always False, meaning bot stuck in infinite loop of greeting user. Not sure if it's dict.copy() issue. Maybe there is a logical way to solve the issue, obv people already figured that out, but my question related to logic more than tools inside bot api.